# How to type annotate a recursive data structure in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, type-annotation

I want to create a simple nested dictionary what is ultimately str-to-str mappings.  As a dictionary, an example instance might look like:

```
{
  'l_0_0': 'string_0',
  'l_0_1': 'string_1',
  'l_0_2': {
     'l_2_0': {
        'l_3_0': 'another_string'
     }
  }
}
```

A less descriptive type annotation might look like `Dict[str, Any]`, but I want to enforce something more specific than `Any` for my search across this tree.

```
def do_something(t: Dict[str, Any]):
    # Do some really cool algorithm
```

Comment: `mypy`, at least, does not support recursive types at the moment, which is what you are looking for (something like `D = Dict[str,Union[str,'D']]`).